# Spring 3.1 Java based configuration -- IllegalStateException

Tags: spring, configuration, illegalstateexception

I am working my way through a Spring tutorial, I have the following code, using Java based configuration, that isn't working.  In my classpath I have the Spring 3.1 jars, as well as asm-4.0.jar and cglib-2.2.2.jar.

MainApp.java:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                HelloWorldConfig.class);
        HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
        helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
        helloWorld.getMessage();
    }
}
```

HelloWorldConfig.java:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {
    @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:456)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:437)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:68)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:448)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Looks like problem with  version of cglib http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366403/java-lang-verifyerror-class-net-sf-cglib-core-debuggingclasswriter

Comment: Which exact versions of which Spring, cglib, and asm jars do you use?

Comment: i also had the same problem, after changing from latest versions to cglib-2.1_3.jar and asm-1.5.3 application ran successfully. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the asm jar file from asm-4.0.jar to asm-3.3.jar, and it worked.  There must have been a conflict between the first asm jar and the cglib jar I was using.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as this and I'm a complete newbie with java and the spring framework. Can someone give more details on how to fix this. I'm using spring 3.4 release with 32 bit jdk1.7.0_51. the error i'm getting is when I try to define an AppConfig.java file for use with my Application.java main class.

Answer (score 1):

I was using cglib-2.1_3.jar and asm 3.1.jar when I ran in to this problem for the first time. After I removed the asm 3.1.jar and added asm- 1.5.3.jar it started working.

Answer (score 0):

**I was use cglib-2.1_3.jar and asm- 1.5.3, after using this jar my program run successfully.**

1. [ASM Core » 1.5.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm/1.5.3)
2. [cglib-2.1_3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcglib213jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this answer in case someone runs into the weird corner case issue I experienced.

This can also happen when the Jar file isn't properly signed.