# Cannot load configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I am following [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm) tutorial about how to use Spring and based on the provided example, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:9)
Caused by: org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:237)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:368)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:219)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5aece24"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    ... 18 more
```

I have researched my problem and have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681188/spring-3-1-java-based-configuration-illegalstateexception); someone also has had the same problem as me, and it has something to do with ensuring that ASM is compatible with CGLIB. However I have tried this solution and it has  not worked, I even went as far as using the exact same versions as the one provided (GBLIB 2.2.2 and ASM 3.3.1).

What do I need to do in order to correct this?

---

For simplicity, here are the files which I am using that were extracted from the provided tutorial.

HelloWorldConfig.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

    @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
        return new HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                HelloWorldConfig.class);

        HelloWorld helloWorld = ctx.getBean(HelloWorld.class);

        helloWorld.setMessage("Hello World!");
        helloWorld.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Also by saying 'However I have tried this solution and it has  not worked' I mean that the exact same error is returned.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? This can make a difference when using a byte code manipulation library like ASM.

Comment: Spring version? They're shading some of the bytecode manipulation now.

Comment: @drembert JavaSE-1.7

Comment: @chrylis sorry that was the Spring Tool Suite version, the IDE I am using in order to use Spring. The Spring version is 4.0.2.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and realized the JRE version I have in the POM.xml or the default one associated with the project was not set in the class path. So updated the same under Preferences -> Installed JREs and ran the application it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Gone through this problem yesterday and
Here is the solution.

1. Open Eclipse
2. Open window in menu bar -> preferences -> java ->installed jre
3. add new jre which is installed in system(c:program_files->java->jre->bin) add it.
4. Select the new added jre and BOOOM

Answer (score 4):

```
This problem occurred due to spring dependency problem, I too used below dependency facing same issue, the configuration classes didn't loaded

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Try below one: for me it is working 

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, i would say the "other" you mentioned, has an different problem.
Even when the "Last-Shown-Exception" is the same as yours.
But as you can see in your stacktrace, the "source" is a **SecurityException**.

The *Cannot load configuration class*-Error is a aftereffect

I assume there is something wrong with the "code signation" in your project
or, due to ByteCode-Manipulation, the signation is broken.

**PS**:
Sometimes this also can happen, when you reference "SignedLibs" **and** "UnsignedLibs" in your project.
in this case remove the signation from the signed libs.

Comment: How do I go about removing the signation from the signed libs?

Comment: open the Jar with any Zip-Archiver, edit the Manifest-file (Meta-Inf folder) and remove the all the lines where the Java-Classes have signing infos... Further you can remove the *.rsa files in Meta-Inf folder.

Comment: What does a signing info look like? Like this? `Name: org/springframework/context/weaving/AspectJWeavingEnabler.class
SHA1-Digest: l50iHSxP9TMDMpK9ncKZNZuDX4M=`

Comment: yes, remove all this entries to remove the signature info.also remove the sf and dsa files in meta-inf dir

Comment: Ok I've done that, however the system is now stating that `The import org.springframework.context cannot be resolved`.

Comment: I'll be specific on what I have done, I got the jar, unzipped it, went in META-INF, edit MANIFEST.MF by removing all of the signatures, and I've deleted .RSA and .SF (no .DSA) from the folder. I then zipped it back, converted it back into a .JAR and used it to replace the original. I refreshed the project so that it uses the updated JAR, however when I do do that, the system returns several errors, primarily due to the fact that it cannot import the required JAR (`The import org.springframework.context cannot be resolved`)

Comment: everything sounds correct, except the part with the exception. It looks like you have problems with some dependencies of your project. NOTE: do not remove class-path info from Manifest

Comment: How will I know the difference between class-path info and signature info?

Comment: Actually just in case, which JAR file should I be doing this on?

Comment: "Class-Path:" is own section in Meta-Inf. you need to unsign *all referenced jars*

Comment: And just to make sure, which JAR file should I be doing this to?

Comment: as is said, to all JARs which are on your classpath. Normally this is not needed! But in case of different signatures or in case of "only some/few JARs are signed", signation must be removed or re-created. The message from the exception is: **class "com.tutorialspoint.HelloWorldConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b5aece24"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package**

Comment: I still can't get it to work, the MANIFEST file has no 'Class-Path' information to speak of, and the moment I make any type of alteration to the file it becomes unreadable, all I know is it has something to do with the `org.springframework.context`library.

Comment: a JAR file is a regular ZIP file, so modifications to it should not make it unreadble.Class-Path info is only needed when you start your program with JAVA -jar yourJarFile.jar. ALL Jars which are on your classpath must be signed with the same certificate! The error message says: there is at least one class (in same package), which is not signed like the others. Does your problematic class maybe exists in different JARs?

Answer (score 0):

All jars required for this project to run: 
    1) org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar 
    2) spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar 
    3) org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar 
    4) commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 
    5) asm-3.3.1.jar 
    6) cglib-2.2.2.jar

To get these jars,either add the downloaded jars to your project directly, or provide the following dependencies in the pom.xml to get them automatically downloaded for you.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Add this to your maven settings.xml file if not already present:

```
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>SPRINGLEARN</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>thirdPartyRepo</id>
                    <name>Third party repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>thirdPartyPluginRepo</id>
                    <name>Third party plugin repository</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

After this, just run your project.
-Right click on your project -> Run as -> Maven clean 
-Right click on your project -> Run as -> Maven install 
-Right click on your project -> Run as -> Java application

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue.
Use the latest version of spring. works in versions of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the POM.xml for suitable dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WTVc.png)
and also JRE as well... it will work with java 1.7

Comment: You have included a link to the picture of code, which is not a proper way to share code on StackOverflow. If you need to share code, please paste it directly in the answer and use code formatting feature.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered the same problem. I tried working with different versions.
But same error occured when I used versions below 5.1.0.RELEASE...
But It is working fine for all the versions from 5.1.0.RELEASE

Sample code:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now I think its clear.