# ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized error, need tip

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.w3schools.blog/spring-boot-with-mysql-database-example) tutorial from W3schools for SpringBoot.

This is how my project looks like:

[image]

I followed the tutorial and changed the pom.xml to what it shows in the above link. Then, I copied the App.java class from the tutorial and put it into DemoApplication.java. Lastly, the controller class was also copied into JDBCController.java.

DemoApplication.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

JDBCController.java:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class JDBCController {
    @Autowired  
    JdbcTemplate jdbc;  

    @RequestMapping("/insert")  
    public String insertData(){  
        jdbc.execute("insert into users(seq,user_name)values(12,'hkumar')");  
        return"Data inserted Successfully";  
    }
}
```

When I run everything these are the errors I get:

```
2022-09-01 12:07:59.268  INFO 1872 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on WSAMZN-4GEVUIP3 with PID 1872 (D:\Users\stefano.pozzi\eclipse-workspace\demo\target\classes started by stefano.pozzi in D:\Users\stefano.pozzi\eclipse-workspace\demo)
2022-09-01 12:07:59.271  INFO 1872 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-09-01 12:07:59.330  INFO 1872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7756c3cd: startup date [Thu Sep 01 12:07:59 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-09-01 12:07:59.929 ERROR 1872 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication   

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.example.demo.DemoApplication
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:419) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:266) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:409) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
... 12 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
... 15 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
... 22 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @5884a914
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
... 30 common frames omitted

2022-09-01 12:07:59.930  INFO 1872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7756c3cd: startup date [Thu Sep 01 12:07:59 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
2022-09-01 12:07:59.931  WARN 1872 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7756c3cd: startup date [Thu Sep 01 12:07:59 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]

2022-09-01 12:07:59.932 ERROR 1872 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7756c3cd: startup date [Thu Sep 01 12:07:59 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
```

I am a bit lost D:

---

I tried putting JDBCController.java with DemoApplication.java. Unfortunately it does not fix the issue :(

[image]

Comment: Seems similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/q/25585601/6150881

Answer (score 0):

Remove the JDBCController.java from the "src/test/java" and move it to the "src/main/java" package.

Comment: Tried and does not fix it :(

Comment: are you still getting the same exception? can you share the main class please?

Comment: done and yes I get the same exact errors

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong JAVA version for the project...........