# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer when deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I 'm building web application using Spring framework and Google App Engine. In dev server it works but when deploying to Google App Engine server I hit this error

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer
```

and

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

The first error show that I seem to miss  net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer in cglib.jar but when I check it's already existed. I can't understand the second log

I use several jars file in classpath:

```
asm-4.0
asm-util-4.0
cglib-3.0
app engine sdk 1.7.6
spring framework 3.2.0
```

What is problem ? and how can I fix ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls check if this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366403/java-lang-verifyerror-class-net-sf-cglib-core-debuggingclasswriter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Spring 3.2 already includes cglib and asm (see item 4.21 of the release notes: http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.2.html). They are in the spring-core jar.

You should try removing the asm and cglib jars from the classpath and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the cglib dependency from the appium java-client as below in the pom.xml file. This fixed the issue for me after tons of google search.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>7.3.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```